# Excel countA to include multiple columns

Tags: forms, excel, spreadsheet

I am having problems with the following formula in excel:

```
=counta(iferror(filter('Form Responses'!F:F, 'Form Responses'!F:F =A2)))
```

Basically Form Responses is a separate sheet, all i am trying to do is make this formula look at multiple columns and count the responses from all of those columns so Form Responses F, G, H,I and so on.

Can anyone help me in correcting this?

Regards

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=COUNTIF('Form Responses'!F:F, "="& A2)

multiple Columns (until Column AA):

=COUNTIF('Form Responses'!F:AA, "="& A2)